# Want to get rid of columns with certain names

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
D 
 1 2 3 4 gene.1 gene.2
 0.1 0.2 0.1 ENS1 ENS2
 0.3 0.3 0.8 ENS5 ENS4
```

I want to get rid of the gene.1 and gene.2 from the data frame.

I understand that I can do D$gene.1 = NULL and D$gene.2 = NULL but with different files, it will end up being different numbers like gene.5 and gene.34

Is there a way to grep these columns by the keyword "gene" and then delete them from the data frame?

Comment: The format of your dataset is not clear. Can you please edit the question with the output of `dput(D)`?

Answer (score 0):

Assign your dataframe to this:

```
df <- df[,grepl("gene", colnames(df)) ==F]
```

This will remove all columns that match the regex pattern

Comment: `==F` is never necessary. `df[,!grepl("gene", colnames(df))]` is clearer (imo).

Comment: Thanks b <3 u da bomb